# Are Dart/Flutter tests executed synchronously or asynchronously

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, asynchronous, testing

could someone explain please how Flutter/Dart tests are executed using test runner?

Are the tests executed synchronously or asynchronously?

Does the testing framework execute every single test synchronously, meaning that only a single test and test suite is executed at any single time?

Or does the testing framework only execute a single test at a time within a test suite, but are able to execute multiple test suites at the same time?

Or testing framework run all tests and test suites completely independent of each other at the same time, completely asynchronously?

This is important because it has a direct impact on the way we are or aren't able to structure our tests, especially when it comes to the set up and tear downs of tests, and the way we assert functionality is working correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general, `dart test` will execute many tests in parallel (the parallelism level varies based on CPU core count), but you can disable this with a command line flag.

You should not write tests with any inter-dependence (i.e. one test should not rely on some global state set up by another test). For example, you may find that because your laptop has a different CPU configuration to your CI server, your tests might pass locally but fail in CI due to different ordering.

If you have some setup logic that is very expensive, and needs to be reused between multiple tests, you can use `setUpAll()` to run some code once before every test in a test group, however this is still discouraged. Personally, I prefer to just join the tests into one long test, to keep all tests self-contained.

This has some advantages. For example, you can use `--total-shards` and `--shard-index` to parallelize tests in CI (by creating multiple jobs to each run a different subset of the test suite).

You can also randomize the order of your tests with `--test-randomize-ordering-seed`, to make sure you aren't accidentally setting up such dependences between tests that might invalidate their results (i.e. perhaps `test2` only passes if it happens after `test1`, randomizing the ordering will catch this).

### TLDR

Many tests run in parallel. Try to keep tests self-contained, with no dependence on the order of tests. Extract setup logic into functions and pass it into `setUp`. If you really *really* need the performance, you can try `setUpAll` but avoid it if possible.